# where is the media permalink info stored in database?

Tags: permalinks, database

When I upload any media it showing me media permalink but, it actually stored in the database.Please help me?

Answer (score 0):

When you upload any media. you are actually creating a new post, with type, `attachment`, so you permalink is stored in exactly the same way as a normal post, in the table.. `YOU_PREFIX_posts`. It is also stored with its own meta_data, again same as normal post type, stored in `YOUR_PREFIX_postmeta`.